# Angular routing - trigger active route but change nothing else

Tags: angular, routes

In Angular 8 I've got a navigation menu that's currently working fine, if you click a link in the nav you get taken to that page, all good. On some links there are sublinks, when you click the parent link in the nav the sublinks appear underneath and the router opens the first component as a default selection.

I've to change this now so that when you click the parent it just makes the sublinks visible but you don't navigate anywhere. I thought it would be a matter of just showing / hiding the sub items on click but the URL doesn't change if I do that. If I set an empty route it shows a blank page which is also no good.

For example imagine a nav item 'Details' which when clicked triggers a route called /details - the url is updated, the sub nav items appear underneath in the nav but nothing else happens. Then if the user clicks a sub nav item (e.g. Personal Details) they go to /Details/personal and the component changes, url updates etc as normal.

So the parent link triggers the routerLinkActive but without changing component. Is this going against how routing should work?